# Question regarding $\iint_{D}^{}(xy+1)dxdy$ where $C: x=3\cos t, y=2\sin t, (0\leqslant t \leqslant 2\pi) $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I need to draw the graph of the area $D$ covered by the two curves and then find the actual value using a multiple integral listed above. The parameters are: $$C: x=3\cos(t), y=2\sin(t) ,(0\leqslant t \leqslant 2\pi) $$

Using the Jacobian functions $x$ becomes $x=3r\cos(\theta )$ and $y$ becomes $y=2r\sin(\theta )$. In addition, the area $D$ moves to $E: 0\leqslant r \leqslant  1, 0\leqslant \theta \leqslant 2\pi $(according to the answers). How does the range of $r$ become $0⩽r⩽1$ if we get an ellipse?

Comment: $(\frac  x 3, \frac y 2)$ lies on the circle of radius $1$ with center at the origin.

Comment: How do you get $(\frac{x}{3},\frac{y}{2})$?

Comment: The range of $r$ is correct. Note that, here, the distance of a point $(x,y)$ from the center $(0,0)$ is not $r$, but 
$$d=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r\sqrt{9\cos^2(\theta)+4\sin^2(\theta)}=r\sqrt{4+5\cos^2(\theta)}.$$ 
For instance, for $r=1$ and  $\theta=0$ we have that $d=3$, and for $r=1$ and  $\theta=\pi/2$ we have that $d=2$.